# Multiplication of matrix with threads problem

Tags: c++, linux

When I try to start my program it keeps saying "undefined reference to 'pthread_create' and 'pthread_join'  .   The program is supposed to multiply two matrix A and B and the result should be put in matrix C, the first thread should calculate first 2 rows of matrix C, and the 2nd thread is supposed to calculate the 2nd two rows of matrix C. The program also works fine without the threads. I'm new to threads so I can't figure out where I messed up, hope someone could help me out?

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <csignal>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;


int MAX_m, MAX_n, MAX_l;

int *matA = new int[MAX_m * MAX_l];
int *matB = new int[MAX_m * MAX_l];
int *matC = new int[MAX_l * MAX_l];

int rd_i = 0;

void* umnoz(void* arg)
{
    int i = rd_i++;

    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_l; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < MAX_m; k++)
        {
            matC[i * MAX_l + j] += matA[i * MAX_m + k] * matB[k * MAX_l + j];
        }
    }
}


pthread_t *dretve;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MAX_l = atoi(argv[1]);
    MAX_m = atoi(argv[2]);
    MAX_n = atoi(argv[3]);


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_l; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_m; j++)
        {
            matA[i * MAX_m + j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_l; j++)
        {
            matB[i * MAX_l + j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Mnozenik: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_l; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_m; j++)
        {
            cout << matA[i * MAX_m + j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Mnozitelj: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_l; j++)
        {
            cout << matB[i * MAX_l + j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    dretve = new pthread_t [MAX_n];


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_n; i++)
    {
        int *p;
        pthread_create(&dretve[i], NULL, umnoz, (void *) (p));
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_n; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(dretve[i], NULL);
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Umnozak: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_l; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_l; j++)
        {
            cout << matC[i * MAX_l + j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you link `pthread` library? `g++ -lpthread main.cpp`?

Comment: Why are you not using [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) from the C++ Standard Library ?

Comment: Oh true, I didnt do that. Thank you.

Comment: Now it just said "Segmentation Fault".

Comment: If anyone knows why it says Segmentation Fault please tell me what to fix, ty! :)

Comment: @Zoof Debugger would know

Comment: Make sure all of the indexing math is correct. Interesting fun fact: None of the included headers are guaranteed to pull in iostream, and that's needed for `cout`.

Comment: Side note: Consider using `std::vector` instead of `new`. It has an `at` method that makes it obvious if the program goes out of bounds . Slows the program down a bit, but great for testing. Plus it takes care of all of the takes care of all the memory management scut work for you.

Comment: `MAX_m` and `MAX_l` are zero at the time `int *matA = new int[MAX_m * MAX_l];` is executed, so `matA` points to an array of zero size. `matA[anything]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds, for any value of `anything`